# Open Specified Workbooks Only

Tags: excel, vba

I run this code daily that will affect each .xlsx workbook in the directory, but how can I ignore the workbook if the file name is not in the "Okay" array?

This is my current syntax:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub OpenExcelInDir()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
    MyFolder = "C:\ExcelSheets"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
        MyFile = Dir
        Call UpdateAllSheets
    Loop
End Sub
```

Now I want to alter it so that I can declare a string array and only open the workbooks in the array something like so:

```
Dim goodWB() As String
goodWB= Split("ABC123,DEF456,GHI789", ",")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you are asking for.  I added a line to test if the file name matched one in the array.

**Tested**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub OpenExcelInDir()
Dim goodWB() As String
goodWB = Split("ABC123.xlsx,DEF456.xlsx,GHI789.xlsx", ",")
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
MyFolder = "C:\ExcelSheets"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")
Do While MyFile <> ""
    If IsInArray(MyFile, goodWB) Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
        MyFile = Dir
        Call UpdateAllSheets
    End If
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Comment: Be aware that the `Filter` function search for partial matches or a subset of the string used as a filter. Therefore its results do not comply with the OP's  requirements as in the case the folder contains a file named `xABC123.xlsx` it will be opened as it's a partial match of the intended file `ABC123.xlsx`

Comment: @EEM You have a good point except that's why I changed the array to include the file extension.  It's extremely unlikely the file name with extension will be included inside another file name.  Give it a try, AABC123 or ABC1233 will not be found, only ABC123.  So... I belive this does comply with the OP's requirement and is just another way of doing it.  Not the fastest but it avoids another loop and works using most of the original code.  Cheers

Comment: I tried that already read thus my comment. Programming wise is not good when a program it's unlikely not to fail, than it most certainly fail. It's a matter of standards and quality...

Answer (score 2):

Even though I like the `IsInArray` function I think the algorithm is utterly inefficient. If you have 1000 files in that folder you will create 1000 temp arrays if one of the few given filenames match. Furthermore, I would expect that after opening one of the wanted files the code would not test against this name anymore (which is not the case).
Instead I propose to look at the problem from the other end:

```
Public Sub OpenExcelInDir()
    Dim goodWB, filename
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String

    goodWB = Array("ABC123.xls", "DEF456.xlsx", "GHI789.xlsx")
    MyFolder = "C:\ExcelSheets"

    For Each filename In goodWB
        MyFile = MyFolder & "\" & filename
        If Len(Dir(MyFile)) > 0 Then
            Workbooks.Open filename:=MyFile
            Call UpdateAllSheets
        End If
    Next WB
End Sub
```

Here, the `Dir()` function is used to test for the existance of the wanted filename in the specified folder. As an additional advantage there won't be any ambiguities like EEM mentioned in his/her comment.

Comment: Agree it is better to use the array contents rather than test each file against the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub OpenExcelInDir()
Const kExt As String = ".xlsm"      `As extension is fixed it could be defined as a constant to avoid repetition
Dim aWbks As Variant, vItm As Variant   ‘Suggest to define the array in one step choose the form you prefer
‘aWbks = Array("ABC123", "DEF456", "GHI789")
aWbks = [{"ABC123", "DEF456", "GHI789"}]

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
    MyFolder = "C:\ExcelSheets"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*" & kExt)

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        For Each vItm In aWbks
            If vItm & kExt = MyFile Then
                Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
                Call UpdateAllSheets
                Exit For
        End If: Next
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```